# Long url is not wrapped

Tags: lyx, line-breaking, urls

In my report I have a long url in my bibliography section. it is not formatted as the other references. I followed [this](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=22526) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640111/url-latex-linebreak-problem) articles for that. But I cannot solve my issue. I am using `LyX`

This is my reference `url` I have an issue with

```
. 2014. . [ONLINE] Available at: http://www.stat.purdue.edu/~doerge/BIOINFORM.D/FALL07/MarjoramTavareNRG2006.pdf. [Accessed 29 November 2014].
```

this is how it is shown in pdf

[image]

In my `preamble` I tried the answers in above articles. But I ended up with no luck.

This  is my preamble.

```
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\author{Viraj Gamage}
\title{}


\newenvironment{indentation}[3]{\par\setlength{\parindent}{#3}
\setlength{\leftmargin}{#1}       \setlength{\rightmargin}{#2}%
\advance\linewidth -\leftmargin       \advance\linewidth -\rightmargin%
\advance\@totalleftmargin\leftmargin  \@setpar{{\@@par}}%
\parshape 1\@totalleftmargin \linewidth\ignorespaces}{\par}%


% new LaTeX commands


\newcommand*{\titleGP}{\begingroup % Create the command for including the title page in the document
\centering % Center all text
\vspace*{\baselineskip} % White space at the top of the page

\rule{\textwidth}{1.6pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace*{2pt} % Thick horizontal line
\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\\[\baselineskip] % Thin horizontal line

{\LARGE Information Technology Based Tools and Approaches \\ For \\[0.3\baselineskip]  ~Genetic Analysis}\\[0.2\baselineskip] % Title

\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace{3.2pt} % Thin horizontal line
\rule{\textwidth}{1.6pt}\\[\baselineskip] % Thick horizontal line

\scshape % Small caps
A LITERATURE REVIEW PRESENTED
TO UNIVERSITY OF COLOMBO SCHOOL OF
COMPUTING
\\ % Tagline(s) or further description
IN CANDIDACY FOR THE DEGREE OF BACHELOR
IN COMPUTER SCIENCE \\[\baselineskip] % Tagline(s) or further description
SCS 3017,  LITERATURE SURVEY\par % Location and year

\vspace*{2\baselineskip} % Whitespace between location/year and editors

COMPLETED by \\[\baselineskip]
{\Large m.g.w. lakshitha \\ reg: no - 2011cs081 \\ index no - 11000813\par} % Editor list
{\itshape University of Colombo School of Computing\par} % Editor affiliation

\vspace*{2\baselineskip}

SUPERVISED by \\[\baselineskip]
{\Large Mrs. m. w. a. c. r. wijesinghe \\ BSc(Pdn), PGDip(Col), MSc(Col), MPhil(Col)\par} % Editor list

\vfill
{ REFERENCE STYLE : HARVARD \\ WORD COUNT : 5266\\ TOOLS USED : LyX, Mendeley \par}


\vspace*{2\baselineskip}

{ december 10, 2014 \par}


\endgroup}
```

Can you please tell me how to solve this issue. And where to put any codes in preamble

Thank you!

Comment: It would be helpful if you turned your code snippets into a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem.

Comment: sorry I did not get you, this is the first time I am using latex and lyx

Comment: Click on the MWE link in the first comment to learm more about a Minimum Working Example. Basically, anything you can do to help save some time for the person trying to help would go a long way to resolving the issue. It is easier to solve a problem if it can first be reproduced so with a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) people can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem, instead of first spending time setting up the problem.